# Rust Match pattern: Bind literal value for specific cases

Tags: rust

I do have the following match statement

```
match it.peek() {
     Some('0') | Some('1') | Some('2') | Some('3')
   | Some('4') | Some('5') | Some('6') | Some('7')
   | Some('8') | Some('9') => { list.push(...) }
     _ => {...}
}
```

Now I would like to write a simply get the element in the `Some` cases, I'm certain this will not work but you'll get the idea from it:

```
match it.peek() {
     Some('0' as digit) | Some('1' as digit) | Some('2' as digit) | Some('3' as digit)
   | Some('4' as digit) | Some('5' as digit) | Some('6' as digit) | Some('7'  as digit)
   | Some('8' as digit) | Some('9' as digit) => { list.push(digit) }
     _ => {...}
}
```

Is this possible? I know I can nest a second match the unpacks the character from the digit, but then I need to implement the `_` case twice, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: Per the duplicate: `Some(digit @ '0') | Some(digit @ '1')`  (and so on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a conditional matching with `char::is_digit`:

```
fn main() {
    let c = Some('2');
    match c {
        Some(c) if c.is_digit(10) => println!("Found a digit: {}", c),
        _ => println!("Found another thing"),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this

```rust
match it.peek() {
    Some(c)
        if *c == '0'
            || *c == '1'
            || *c == '2'
            || *c == '3'
            || *c == '4'
            || *c == '5'
            || *c == '6'
            || *c == '7'
            || *c == '8'
            || *c == '9' => {}
}
```

which seems to do the trick. Still interested in better ways

Comment: You could make this shorter by using [is_digit](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.is_digit):

`Some(c) if c.is_digit(10) => { ... }`